# Pick .mp3 file from sdcard in preferencescreen

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, filepicker, preferencescreen

How i can pick mp3 file from sdcard in android preferenceScreen menu..

here is my preferenceScreen:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/app_setting">

            <Preference android:title="@string/ChooseRingtone"
                android:key="sdPref" />

        </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

here my SettingActivity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity{
      @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            android.app.Fragment infoFragment = new MyPreferenceFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, infoFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
      public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        private AppSettings settings;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);

            Preference sdPrefs = findPreference("sdPref");
            sdPrefs.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

what i dont know is how to open sdcard and choose only .mp3 extension files from whole sdcard. and how to store that mp3 file to my asset/raw directory if it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code for selecting only mp3 files,

```
       sdPrefs.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                 Intent intent_upload = new Intent();
                 //intent_upload.setType("audio/*"); // For All Audio Files
                 intent_upload.setType("audio/mp3"); // For only MP3 Files
                 intent_upload.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                 startActivityForResult(intent_upload,1);
                 return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: in startActivityForResult second argument is not integer

Comment: its character sequnce

Comment: Second argument is unique id for checking response your get, and generally it is int, you can take it as declare first at top int PICK_SONG = 1, and then pass it as second argument, 

When you will get result in onActivityResult, you need to match this tag for proper response.

Comment: hey is it possible to store selected mp3 file to raw directory?

Comment: nope you can't do it, instead of that you should store file path in db or preferences and use it, it will reduce memory and run faster.

Comment: how to store file path in Preference